# Vuejs "Cannot read property.." on Element GUI select component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hey guys shorty question: i'm using the GUI components of element.eleme.io http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select
my problem now is, when i try to make a custom option template and want to display the user name, in the console log i get error "Cannot read property 'name' but when i put out the data of user, it shows all properties.
here is the code snippet:

```
<el-select v-model="filterUsersPostData.user"
    remote
    placeholder="Select"
    :remote-method="searchUsers"
    @change="changeUser"
    id="assigned-user">
    <el-option
        v-for="user in filterUsers"
        :label="user.name"
        :value="user.id">
        <pre>@{{ user }}</pre>
        <span><img :src="user.image" />@{{ user.name }}</span>
    </el-option>
</el-select>
```

the image src is rendered correctly allthough it is also called through user.image. the @ in front of the {{ is because i'm using it in Laravel.

the objects look like:

```
{
  "id": "2205c9525f86571eff1716ec3af734b4",
  "name": "Joen Doe",
  "image": "/media/502e43ad71e844b0d502bc9ac60816eb/img/users/2205c9525f86571eff1716ec3af734b4/jon-doe.jpg"
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is contained in the `filterUsers` object?

Comment: Which version of Vue do you use ? Because in version 2.2.0+ you must indicate a `key` when render `v-for` of components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key.  If key is not the problem can you see if you have warning in your browser console.